# React native firebase auth with facebook crashes app

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-firebase, react-native-fbsdk

After upgrading targetSdkVersion from 30 to 31 my facebook authentication crashes app without any visible error.

For exapmle google auth using firebase is working perfectly. This issue appears only using Facebook auth.

```
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
    minSdkVersion = 21
    compileSdkVersion = 31
    targetSdkVersion = 31
    ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
    fitnessVersion = "20.0.0"
    supportLibVersion = "30.0.0"
    kotlin_version = '1.6.0'
}
```

Package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^14.1.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^14.1.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^14.1.0",
    "react-native-fbsdk-next": "^4.6.0",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.2",
    ...
}
```

JDK version

```
javac 11.0.15.1
```

Answer (score 0):

react-native-fbsdk-next must be 5+

```
"react-native-fbsdk-next": "^5.0.0",
```

Features:
android, sdks: use facebook-android-sdk v12+, target/compile SDK 31